# Mocking a static final method using PowerMock

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, static-methods, final, powermock

I have class with all the methods static and final. How do I mock a method which is both static and final in the class.

```java
public class UtilityClass{
  public static final void utilityMethod(){
  }

  public static final Integer anotherUtilMethod(){
  }
}
```

How to mock `utilMethod()` and `anotherUtilMethod()` using PowerMock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final UtilityClass util = PowerMockito.mock(UtilityClass.class);
PowerMockito.mockStatic(UtilityClass.class);
```

Then use PowerMockito.when() like you normally would. Look at http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13 for examples.

Comment: Why do you have to put the first line over there?

Comment: @michael there isn't enough information for this answer to be helpful. Please add more detail.

Comment: Not working in case of Class is `final` and method is `static final`.